# Rails - bootstrap tags input - tags rendering as single tag on validation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using [bootstrap tags input](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) to handle tag submission.  I am also using acts-as-taggable-on.

Entering information in the form works fine.  Submitting a correctly filled out form works.  However when there is a validation failure the page will render with previous tags combined into a single tag.

Here is some html before submission

```
<form action="/items" method="post">
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
    <span class="tag label label-info">
        "foo"<span data-role="remove"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="tag label label-info">
        "bar"<span data-role="remove"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="tag label label-info">
        "foobar"<span data-role="remove"></span>
    </span> 
</div>
<input type="text" value name="item[tag_list]" id="item_tag_list" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

and after validation failure

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
    <span class="tag label label-info">
        "foo bar foobar"<span data-role="remove"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
  def create
    Item.transaction do

      @item= Item.create(name: item_params[:name],
                                        tag_list: item_params[:tag_list], 
                                        created_by: current_user.id,
                                        status: Item::STATUS[:pending])


      if @item.errors.empty?
        @user_item = @item.user_items.build(user_id: current_user.id)

        if @user_item.save
          flash[:notice] = "Thank you for your item request! Your request will be processed within the next 5 days."
          redirect_to items_path
        else
          render :new
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "UserItem create failed"
        end

      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end

private

    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :tag_list)
    end
end
```

I need a way for this param to display as multiple tags as it was when the user entered it.

Answer (score 0):

When you set tag_list with a string delimited by commas it becomes an array of strings.  If the validation fails I need to set the tag_list attribute to a string of tags.  These two lines helped me accomplish this.

```
@item.tag_list.remove(item_params[:tag_list], parse: true)
@item.tag_list.add(item_params[:tag_list])
```